# How to calculate all the x values given a number of coordinates?

Tags: python

For instance, a function would take a set of *n* points like:  { (x0, y0), (x1, y1), … (xn-1, yn-1) }.
The function would then return the sum of all these x coordinates:  x0 + x1 + x2 + … + xn-1.

So, here is what I have tried to do so far,

```py
def sum_x(l):
    sum(l,key=lambda x:[0])
```

Comment: The `sum` function does not take any keyword argument, in particular it does not take the `key` keyword argument. You are also creating a function for something that can be done in one line of code which is often unnecessary. You are also not explicitly returning anything from the function, so the result will always be `None`. A simple `sum(point[0] for point in points)` would do the job here.

Comment: What data-structure is the point in exactly? Not sure what "{ (x0, y0), (x1, y1), … (xn-1, yn-1) }" is supposed to represent. Do you mean extract them (rather than calculate or sum them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were kind of close.

You needed to use `x[0]` inside the lambda and you probably want to `return` the calculated sum, but the problem is that `sum` does not accept a `key` function (unlike `sorted`).

However you can use a generator expression:

```
def sum_x(l):
    return sum(element[0] for element in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_x(l):
    return sum(map(lambda t: t[0], l))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.